# Is the a way to specify package version numbers?

Tags: meteor

Sooner or later new versions break old ones. To make Meteor upgrades 
less surprising I would like to be able to specify the version of
packages such as CoffeeScript, LESS, Bootstrap etc. (something like
npm's versioning would be ideal).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) packaging system. It keeps track of the version numbers, or even uses the latest git version depending on what you put in your `smart.json` file.